# How would we prove $\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$?

Tags: proof-writing, computational-complexity

Given a runtime of $\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$, how would we prove that the big-O notation is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. I want to use the $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ formula.

Comment: Have you tried **anything**?

Comment: Since $(n^2 - n)/2 < n^2$ for any $n\geq 1,$ it seems it should be easy to set this up. Have you looked at the $f(n)=O(g(n))$ formula recently?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: By showing that

$$\left|\frac{\frac{n^2-n}2}{n^2}\right|\le C$$

for some positive constant $C\in\Bbb R^+$ and all sufficiently large $n$.